# Spring Cloud API Gateway Routing based on data in JWT

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using Spring Cloud Gateway, I want to route incoming request to ServiceA or ServiceB based on a value in the JWT token. So basically I want to extract the Token and get a userId from it and based on that information route to either service-a and service-b.

So the incoming request is something like "/v1/customers" and I need to prefix it with either /service-a/v1/customers to that it will be route to urlServiceA.

Here is the code of my Routes.

```
@Bean
    public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        
        String urlServiceA = "a";
        
        String urlServiceB = "b";
        
        return builder.routes()
                .route(r -> r.path("/service-a/v1/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.filter(authentication))         
                        .uri(urlServiceA))
                
                .route(r -> r.path("/service-b/v1/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.filter(authentication))         
                        .uri(urlServiceB))
                .build();
    }
```

How can I do it ? Please help.
Thanks

Comment: I assume that `authentication` is a custom filter?

Comment: Yes it is a customer filter. It mainly validate the JWT token.
Before that custom filter is run I need to basically modified the path based on some information in the request payload or inside the request JWT so that the right Custom filter and the right routing is process.

Comment: we have filters to modify the path, based on information in the uri, but not based on the payload or JWT, that will need to be a custom filter